# Symfony 2 Translation of fields entity

Tags: php, frameworks, symfony, entity

For a project I have to have somes fields in entity which need to be in many languages. For example, for an entity `Product`, for the field `description` needs to be in severals languages.

How to do that with Symfony 2?

Answer (score 1):

[`DoctrineExtensions`](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) provide [the functionality](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/translatable.md) you need and [`StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle`](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) provides integration with Symfony.

Comment: Yes, but i have some issue during the install :/

Comment: So symfony propose nothing without taking the risk of an external bundle?